# "Indicates on" or just "indicates"?

Tags: prepositions

What's correct in this sentence?

> Each one of these axes indicates **on**(?) other direction

Comment: A possible alternative: *Each axis has its own direction*; or perhaps *Each axis points in its own direction*.

Comment: Did you see this sentence used somewhere?  If I saw it, I would think it were a typo for "... **one** other direction."

Comment: It's not a typo since I wrote it. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Indicate on" isn't really a possible option here. You may have read a sentence that uses "indicates on," but there is only one context that I can think of that you would find that combination:

> He indicated on the map where the treasure was.

But in this case, "on" is part of "on the map," not of the verb itself.

From what I understand of your question, you're probably looking for:

> Each one of these axes indicates different directions.

You certainly wouldn't use "on" there in any case, though your sentence in its current form doesn't make much sense to me with or without "on."